# Why calling ajax.reload() on DataTable() returns undefined?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I've done this so far. After completely loaded, the table was shown perfectly. But when I added `t.ajax.reload()`, it shows `TypeError: t.ajax is undefined`

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function(oSettings)
{
  return {
    "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
    "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
    "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
    "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
    "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
    "iPage": Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
    "iTotalPages": Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
  };
};

var t = $("#mytable").dataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    var api = this.api();
    $('#mytable_filter input')
    .off('.DT')
    .on('keyup.DT', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        api.search(this.value).draw();
      }
    });
  },
  oLanguage: {
    sProcessing: "loading..."
  },
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {"url": "data/json", "type": "POST"},
  columns: [
    {
      "data": "id",
      "orderable": false
    },
        {"data": "nama"},
        {"data": "stok"},
        {"data": "satuan"},
    {
      "data" : "action",
      "orderable": false,
      "className" : "text-center"
    }
  ],
  order: [[0, 'desc']],
  rowCallback: function(row, data, iDisplayIndex) {
    var info = this.fnPagingInfo();
    var page = info.iPage;
    var length = info.iLength;
    var index = page * length + (iDisplayIndex + 1);
    $('td:eq(0)', row).html(index);
  }
});

setInterval( function () {
  t.ajax.reload();
}, 3000 );
```

Any suggestion will be apreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/api)

> It is important to note the difference between `$( selector ).DataTable()` and `$( selector ).dataTable()`. The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object. An api() method is added to the jQuery object so you can easily access the API, but the jQuery object can be useful for manipulating the table node, as you would with any other jQuery instance (such as using addClass(), etc.).

Therefore :

```
var t = $("#mytable").DataTable({...}); // capital D
```